# Looking for best solution for python's base64.b32encode in php

Tags: php

I am having a code written in python

```
from base64 import b32encode, b32decode

somename = 'Karthik Bhat K'

b32encoded = b32encode(somename)
b32decoded = b32decode(b32encoded)
```

I want to write the b32encode and b32decode code in php because the key generated by python is used by app written in php.

Php does have `base64_encode` but for base32_encode I didn't find any `builtins`

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using custom written function

```
// Note this functions can be improved!
function base32_encode($d): string{
    // position mapping of characters
    list($t, $b, $r) = array("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567", "", "");

    foreach(str_split($d) as $c) {
        // Get 8 bits for each character
        $b = $b . sprintf("%08b", ord($c));
    }

    // Since there are only 32 element in b32encode i.e A-Z and 2-7
    // split the binary with 5 bits in each chunk
    // since 2 ^ 5 is 32, gives items between 0 and 31
    foreach(str_split($b, 5) as $c) {
        // If any group has less than 5 bits fill it with 0 from the right
        if (strlen($c) < 5)
            $c = str_pad($c, 5, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT);

        // bindec converts binary to decimal
        // The decimal is index in the array $t
        // Get the value from the index of array $t
        $r = $r . $t[bindec($c)];
    }

    return($r);
}

function base32_decode($d): string{
    list($t, $b, $r) = array("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567", "", "");
    // Encode just split bit string into set of 5 character each
    // This is the reverse of it. Find index in $t and convert it into
    // 5 bit string and join each of them
    foreach(str_split($d) as $c)
        $b = $b . sprintf("%05b", strpos($t, $c));

    // Each 8 bit of the string $b will give you the decoded string
    foreach(str_split($b, 8) as $c) {
        if (bindec($c)) {  // Ignores the padding given in base32_encode
            $r = $r . chr(bindec($c));
        }
    }

    return($r);
}
```